# Javascript HTML clear all current content and load new content in the same window

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and html. I want to add a button to a page, e.g. "A" button. When I click A, I want the page be cleaned up and show something new such as a text box or something.

I have searched on the internet. The methods I found, such as `document.body.innerHTML=""`, will clean up the whole page with the new elements I want to show after clicking the button, because I have all the html elements loaded already. And it will just clean all of them. I also tried to use a separate html file and put the new stuff there and load it after I click the button. I tried window.open("path of the file on my computer"). But I think this is not correct, as I simply opened a blank page.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: _I have a login.jsp file_ uhm.. where? please provide more details (script/markup) for us to help you

Comment: Isn't that what links are for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are multiple ways to accomplish your task.
Suppose you already have the button A as such in your html:

```
<button name="myButton" onclick="replacePage()">Button A</button>
```

then you can create the event handler function in your javascript:

```
<script>
function replacePage(){
var newElement= "<input type='textbox' name='myTextbox'>";
document.body.innerHTML=newElement;
}
</script>
```

You may also use the document.write() function to replace everything in the page.

You also mentioned linking to another html file. The way to do it is pass "_self" as the second parameter to the window.open() function so it opens the html on the same page:

```
window.open("htmlLink.html", "_self");
```

Comment: I am not clear what htmlink.html should be. I wrote a html file and put on my local disk. Can I put the path of it there?

Comment: Yes. If they are in the same directory, you can simply substitute in the file name.

Comment: I put the whole path such as "C:/.../testpage.html". It did not load the page. If I get rid of the "_self" argument. It will open a new blank page.

Comment: Try putting your testpage.html in the same directory as your main testing html file. And simply put "testpage.html" as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery for this pupose. Put all the the things that you want to replace in a separate "div". And replace the HTML like below;

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("div").html("Hello <b>world</b>!");
});
```

You need to import jQuery as shown below:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not a good idea to suggest a library when it isn't in the tag or posted code and not particularly relevant to the question.

Comment: What if user is unaware and teach him/her something that is easy and new for him?

Answer (score 0):

You can say something like bellow:-

button in HTML

```
<button onclick="changeContent()">Change Content</button>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    function changeContent(){
        var content = "<input type='textbox' name='myTextbox'>";
        document.write(content);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Calling *document.write* after the load event will first call *document.open*, which clears the **entire** content of the page—the doctype, html element, the lot. Then it will write the markup, resulting in an invalid HTML document (though error correction will likely add necessary mandotory components and trip the browser into quirks mode).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. But what I did before when I got this problem. I read the whole .html file and did document.write(htmlfilecontent). so that time it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you. But I want to load more then one element? How to do that?

Comment: Then what can you do as I mentioned in previous comment read the html file and do `document.write(filecontent)`. It will work

Comment: How should do that? Can I create a variable which is a html file? Can you give more detail?

Comment: try to read a file in javascript. and you can get that file content in a variable. I used nodejs to read the files. I am searching how to do in JS.

Comment: "I read the whole .html file" how? If you read an entirely new document, then it is simpler and more efficient to use a link: `<a href="newPage.html">new page</a>`, no script required and works everywhere.

Comment: @RobG Sorry sir forgot to mention, that time I was working on node-webkit. So i used nodejs functions for that.

Comment: I tried put all html content as string to the content variable. And it works. Thanks

Comment: @Liu I think the comments which helped you are seems important for your question. You should vote them, so they  will appear in starting of the post and will be helpful for other viewers. Thanx

Comment: @Mritunjay. Can't vote as newbies.

Comment: @Liu no problems, but whenever you will be able to vote. Please make a habit of doing this, if it's not your post then also. Because if you think this is helpful for you, that will be helpful for others

Comment: @Liu and you haven't accepted any answer also, you should also do that, it'll improve your reputation and value of the answer.

Comment: @Mritunjay I thought I did. I picked the one works most like what I want.

Comment: Ya that's good, now other viewers also came to know that this solution will work in this problem. cheers

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I actually got double points for accepting one answer twice. I will vote other answers next time when I can. The answer I picked this time is the one I adopted and modified in my code.